# How to split string and working with sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am beginner to android..I am using Qr scanner in my app..It displaying result in my app as a toast message like fruit good...but how to  split string ..that string should work with shared preferences..

below is my code

```
 @Override

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
    Intent data) {
    IntentResult customerSno = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, 
     data);
    if (customerSno != null) {
        if (customerSno.getContents() == null) {
            Log.d("ScanFragment", "Cancelled scan");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            Log.d("ScanFragment", "Scanned");
            Toast.makeText(this, " " + customerSno.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setCustomerSerialNoName(customerSno.getContents().toString());
        }
    } else {
        // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    // }

}

private void setCustomerSerialNoName(String cusSno) {
    String customerSNo = IHomeActivity._sharedPreferences.getString("customerSNo", "null");

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = IHomeActivity._sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("customerSNo", cusSno);
    editor.putString("customerPass",passcode);
    if(customerSNo.equals(cusSno)){
    }else{
        editor.putBoolean("custSNoAuthStatus", false);
    }
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: how do you want the split string?

Comment: please write what are you getting from customerSno.getContents() and how do you want to split it

Comment: I am scanning IESA AAAAEXD...i want to split IESA and AAAAEXD separate..and IESA shoud work with passcode in shared preferences and AAAEXD as a customerSNo

Answer (score 0):

String spiting will done if you are using by **`StringTokenzier`**

```
StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenzier(custDesString,",");
ArrayList custDesList= new ArrayList();

while ( stk.hasMoreTokens() ) {
custDesList.add(stk.nextToken()); // all string are store in list
}
```

To retrieve string from list
 get single string from specific position

```
String str1 = custDesList.get(position);
```